# Home page is the only one that works deploying with github pages

Tags: github, http-status-code-404, github-pages, deploying, custom-error-pages

Here is the link to my site. I just deployed it and when I try to navigate to other pages it gives me a 404. Any idea how to fix this?

https://yournamellc.github.io/anime-quote-generator/

Comment: Here is the link to my site and Repo:

https://yournamellc.github.io/anime-quote-generator/

https://github.com/yournamellc/anime-quote-generator

When I deploy with pages my site breaks and looks terrible and only the homepage works but all my css etc. isn't applying lol. Not sure what I'm doing wrong but I would love if someone could help me with fixing this.